# Beginner in Realm Swift - How to instantiate a new Realm in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a class DataEntry that I want to store instances of in a Realm database, but i'm having issue instantiating a Realm. Here is my DataEntry class:

```
class DataEntry: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var exercise = ""
    @objc dynamic var weightLBS = 0
    @objc dynamic var averageBarSpeed = 0
    @objc dynamic var topBarSpeed = 0

}
```

Some context as to what I'll be using it for:
I'd like to have functions to write and delete instances of a DataEntry, but the documentation on that seems fairly simple.

- Adding new dataEntry would be done by a user inputing data into a form
- Deleting dataEntrys will simply be a button
- Planning on reading the data to create graphs to track performance over time

The issue I'm having is instantiating a new Realm, and using the appropriate error handling. I've found a few simpler examples, but they all throw errors so i'm assuming there's something i'm missing. I know you're not supposed to use try!, so I'm wondering, what is a simple way to instantiate a new Realm, so I can then read/write/delete DataEntry's to the Realm Database.

This one gives me multiple "Expected Declaration" errors in lines 1 and 3.

```
do {
      let realm = try Realm()
    } catch let error as NSError {
      // handle error
    }
```

This one gives me an "Expected Declaration" error on line 1

```
try {
    let realm = try Realm()
    } catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Any additional pointers on how to best set up this would be amazing, wether or not I should have a RealmManager class that would aid in error handling. I've seen in some cases people create extensions of Realm, but this is a little too advanced for me right now.

Background in CS, but brand new to both Swift and Realm for context.

Edit/Update:

Quick clarification, I'm having issues with instantiating a Realm. Not a Realm object. I've updated above to be more clear.

To clarify my question, I'm getting errors for what appears to be good code above, so I assume I have it in the wrong place. I get errors when its inside the DataEntry class, when its inside of a view, and at the top level of a SwiftUI file. Any advice on where I should include the c ode for the instantiation would be great!

Comment: Do you instantiate a new Realm object into the `DataEntry` class?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code in your question; when I copy and paste it into a Realm project, it works correctly. However, the question itself is vague and a bit jumbled. You're heading asks about instantiating a new realm object - in this case that would be `let myObject = DataEntry()` - that's a new Realm object. If you asking about a new Realm, well, your code does that. We really need to see more compete code and a clearer description of the issue. Also, for getting started `let realm = try! Realm()` will work as well. Can you clarify the question please?

Comment: Oh, don't forget to `import RealmSwift` at the top of the file as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response. I clarified above, I'm talking about instantiating a Realm, not a Realm object. I believe I have the code in the wrong place (It must be, if you're saying its good code). What rules are there for a Realm instantiation? I get errors when its inside the DataEntry class, when its inside of a view, and at the top level of a SwiftUI file. So I'm not sure where to put this code and have it not throw an error: 
    do {
      let realm = try Realm()
    } catch let error as NSError {
      // handle error
    }

Comment: There are lots of schools of thought on when/where to use the Realm object but when starting, make it easy; whenever you want to use Realm, instantiate an object within the function. For example if you have button that when clicked, writes an object to realm. Within that buttons action handler `let realm = try! Realm()` and then `realm.write {...`. There's a [Realm Tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/ios-swift/)available as well as a project you can download and take a look at. Realm objects are defined globally in code, the Realm itself is often within the function as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help but knowing where to put things within a project can sometimes help understand the flow.

So I created a realm project in XCode that writes a person object with the name of Jay to realm when button 0 is clicked. Then when button 1 is clicked, it retrieves that data and prints to console.

There's no error checking here and I am force unwrapping an optional so don't do that in a real app.

```
import Cocoa
import RealmSwift

class PersonClass: Object {
    @Persisted var name = ""
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBAction func button0Action(_ sender: Any) {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        let jay = PersonClass()
        jay.name = "Jay"
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(jay)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func button1Action(_ sender: Any) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let jay = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).where { $0.name == "Jay" }.first!
        print(jay.name)  //outputs "Jay" to console
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

The project starts with importing RealmSwift and then the Realm object(s) are defined outside of any other classes, so they are at a high level.

Then we have the ViewController with two button actions - as you can see, within each action function, we access realm with

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

and then interact with realm. When that function exits, the realm object is deallocated so it's a safe way to work with Realm and not leave it 'connected'.

Some developers create a singleton or a RealmService class to interact with Realm but singletons can be tricky. I suggest initially going with the pattern shown above (and in the docs).

Answer (score 0):

there has a better way to update and append a new record to Realm in the latest version.

```
@ObservedResults(Group.self) var groups
$groups.append(Group())
TextField("New name", text: $item.name)
```

The documentation is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/), please take some time to read it.
If it is hard for you, I suggest at least finishing this video by code along with her. [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCVsFsY3TvM)